# Cannot see the form input field at all

Tags: python, django

I would like to collect the content that user input, then change the database using POST method. But i just blank when i clicked post button on the website.

Here's the views.py

```
class PostTweet(View):

def post(self, request, username):

    form = TweetForm(request.POST)
    print form.is_valid()
    print request.POST
    print form.errors
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                      user=user,
                      country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
        tweet.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+username)
    else:
        form = TweetForm()

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form':form})

class Profile(View):
    """
    User Profile page reachable from /user/<username> URL
    """
    def get(self, request, username):
        params = {}
        user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user=user)
        params["tweets"] = tweets
        params["user"] = user
        return render(request, 'profile.html', params)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TweetForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=160)
    country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),required=False)
```

profile.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 column">
    <form id="form" method="POST" action="post/">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="col-md-8 fieldWrapper">
        {{ form }}
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Post</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
      <div class="well">
        <span>{{ tweet.text}}</span>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index, Profile, PostTweet, HashTagCloud
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view()),
    url(r'^hashTag/(\w+)/$', HashTagCloud.as_view()),
)
```

Anyone just give me a hint would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Is your form valid? And it doesn't seem like you're including your form on the page either, now that I look at it more closely. There should be a `{{ form }}` or something similar in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: @ddsnowboard i have changed the `profile.html` to add `{{ form }}` like you said. But i could not see the input text filed at all. Would you give me a hand to figure it out?

Comment: @Alasdair Hey bro, I have changed the view and the subject. I hope you will see that :-) What is post_view method ?

Comment: Add some print statements to debug the code, e.g. `print form.is_valid()`. If it is not valid, you could check `form.errors`.

Comment: @Alasdair bro, I added `print form.is_valid()` under the `tweet.save()` but the terminal didn't show boolean value of form.is_valid(). Am i doing the wrong way ?

Comment: Can you post your urls.py? I would put the print statement immediately above `if form.is_valid():`.

Comment: @Alasdair bro, i have post the urls.py. I hope you will see that :-)

Comment: @Alasdair bro, I seen the boolean result. It returned False

Comment: Using `action="post/"` is very fragile. Change it to `action="{% url 'post_tweet' %}"`. You'll need to add url pattern `url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view(), name='post_tweet')`. This won't fix the problem, but it will make the code better.

Comment: If the form is not valid, print `request.POST` and `form.errors` as well.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you bro, i have noticed the errors through your help. But i still could not see the input text field which should be there.

Comment: If you don't see the input text field, what do you see instead? What does your base.html look like?

Comment: Another aside - you don't need `if request.method == 'POST':` in your `post` method, since the `post` method will only be called for post requests!

Comment: @Alasdair I have removed the `if request.method == 'POST':` which is really doesn't influence the result at all. I just seen the post button but nothing at all

Comment: I can't spot the problem at the moment. Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: @Alasdair i have updated the code among `views.py` `forms.py` `profile.html`. I haven't changed the urls.py because i tried the way like you said but i raised another question here 
`Reverse for 'post_tweet' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(\\w+)/post/$']`

Comment: I see, the `url` tag will only work if you include the username. What does the profile view look like? What are the form errors.

Comment: @Alasdair bro, i have updated the code that have included the `profile` view. The form errors said i have to input something in the `country field`. But as i have set the `country field` into HiddenInput method so i could not see the input field. Then i added the `required=False` then the form errors changed into that i have to input something in the text field. But i could not see the text input field at all

Comment: I think it would be better if you used the same url, e.g. `user/(\w+)/` for get and post requests. At the moment, I don't understand what url you use to view the blank form before you fill it out, because I can't anywhere in your views where you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding {{form}} only should not render the field. form is an object with fields as properties. In your html try substituting `{{form}}` with `{{form.text}}`

Also you can try passing the object "form" as follows:

```
return render(request, 'profile.html', form = form)
```

Comment: I still cannot see the input field

Comment: You can help us understand the problem if you copy here the stack trace that you might see in debug mode, or also if, by using inspect element you see if anything is at all loaded in the place where you expect the field to appear. I am pretty comfortable with Flask which is a simpler version of Django and in flask once the object is passed to the template, you can access fields as I pointed out :/

Comment: That's really a good advice bro. I will try the way you tell me. Really appreciate your help :-)